# How to use bang bangs (!!) with fancycut in R?

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I'm trying to cut data using some predefined intervals with fancycut. I want to do this programmatically, i.e. I do not want to go and copy past something like

```
fancycut(age, 0-4 = '[0,4]'....
```

Here is a MWE to show you what I mean:

```
age <- c(19, 41,6, 82, 29, 39, 84, 34, 97, 22)

fancy_labels <- c("00-04", "05-09", "10-14", "15-19", 
                  "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", 
                  "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", 
                  "60-64", "65-69", "70+")

fancy_range <- c("[0, 4]","[5, 9]","[10, 14]","[15, 19]",
                 "[20, 24]","[25, 29]","[30, 34]","[35, 39]",
                 "[40, 44]","[45, 49]","[50, 54]","[55, 59]",
                 "[60, 64]","[65, 69]","[70, Inf]")
```

I would like to just plug in the values from `fancy_range` and the labels from `fancy_labels`. I think this should be possible using the bang bang operator but I'm struggling to make it work.

This

```
fancycut(age, !!fancy_labels = !!fancy_range)
```

does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the unquote-splice operator `!!!` here:

```
rlang::exec( fancycut, age, !!!setNames(fancy_range, fancy_labels) )
#  [1] 15-19 40-44 05-09 70+   25-29 35-39 70+   30-34 70+   20-24
# 15 Levels: 00-04 05-09 10-14 15-19 20-24 25-29 30-34 35-39 40-44 ... 70+
```

Answer (score 1):

The double-bang operator is not native to R, but is a special construct used for selective unquoting within the tidyverse. You can't use it in this context.

To create a call without typing everything out in base R you would have to build a pairlist and turn it into a call, then evaluate it (which is what the `!!` operator effectively does behind the scenes when used in the correct context)

Something like:

```r
eval(as.call(c(fancycut, x = quote(age), 
               setNames(as.list(fancy_range), fancy_labels))))
#> [1] 15-19 40-44 05-09 70+   25-29 35-39 70+   30-34 70+   20-24
#> 15 Levels: 00-04 05-09 10-14 15-19 20-24 25-29 30-34 35-39 40-44 45-49 ... 70+
```

However, you need to fix your input first. You had no `c` before the `age` vector, and your ranges need to be enclosed in curly or straight brackets:

```
age <- c(19, 41,6, 82, 29, 39, 84, 34, 97, 22)

fancy_labels <- c("00-04", "05-09", "10-14", "15-19", "20-24", 
                  "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", 
                  "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70+")

fancy_range <- c("[0, 4]","(5, 9]","(10, 14]","(15, 19]",
                 "(20, 24]","(25, 29]","(30, 34]","[35, 39]",
                 "[40, 44]","[45, 49]","[50, 54]","[55, 59]",
                 "[60, 64]","[65, 69]","[70, Inf]")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fancycut` is a wrapper for `wafflecut`.

```
fancycut
function (x, na.bucket = NA, unmatched.bucket = NA, out.as.factor = TRUE, 
    ...) 
{
    dots <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
    if (length(dots) > 0) {
        buckets <- names(dots)
        intervals <- as.character(dots)
    }
    return(wafflecut(x = x, intervals = intervals, buckets = buckets, 
        na.bucket = na.bucket, unmatched.bucket = unmatched.bucket, 
        out.as.factor = out.as.factor))
}
```

Other than calling the `wafflecut`, there is nothing going on in the function.  So, we can directly call the `wafflecut`

```
wafflecut(age, intervals = fancy_range, buckets = fancy_labels)
#[1] 15-19 40-44 05-09 70+   25-29 35-39 70+   30-34 70+   20-24
#Levels: 00-04 05-09 10-14 15-19 20-24 25-29 30-34 35-39 40-44 45-49 50-54 55-59 60-64 65-69 70+
```